# Renaming exported function using Rcpp::export fails on a specific installation

Tags: r, rcpp

Exporting an Rcpp function with a different name succeeds on one machine but fails on the other. The R environments are very similar. What am I doing wrong?

### Details

I have an R package with an Rcpp function that is exported with the following signature (in `sample_int_crank.cpp`):

```
// [[Rcpp::export(sample.int.crank)]]
IntegerVector sample_int_crank(int n, int size, NumericVector prob) {
    ...
```

This function is declared empty in a corresponding R file (`sample_int_crank.R`):

```
sample.int.crank <- function(n, size, prob) {
}
```

**EDIT**: When I remove this R file, the function is available. But where do I place roxygen2 comments for this function?

Now, when I install the package from GitHub,

```
library(devtools)
install_github('wrswoR', 'muelleki', '0.0.6')
```

on machine **A** it says:

```
> sample.int.crank
internal C++ function <0x29ddc40>
    signature : Rcpp::IntegerVector sample.int.crank(int, int, Rcpp::NumericVector)
```

and on machine **B**:

```
> sample.int.crank
function(n, size, prob) {
}
<environment: namespace:wrswoR>
```

**EDIT**: If `sample_int_crank.R` is removed from the package, the output looks different, but identical on **A** and **B**. What is going on here?

```
library(devtools)
install_github('wrswoR', 'muelleki')

> sample.int.crank
function (n, size, prob) 
{
    .Call("wrswoR_sample_int_crank", PACKAGE = "wrswoR", n, size, 
        prob)
}
<environment: namespace:wrswoR>
```

The `sessionInfo()` seems to be more or less identical, at least for R and Rcpp -- **A**:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.3 (2013-03-01)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] wrswoR_0.0.6    logging_0.7-102 Rcpp_0.10.3     devtools_0.8   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] digest_0.5.2    evaluate_0.4.2  httr_0.1.1      memoise_0.1    
 [5] parallel_2.15.3 plyr_1.7.1.99.2 RCurl_1.95-0    stringr_0.6.1  
 [9] tools_2.15.3    whisker_0.1
```

**B**:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.3 (2013-03-01)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.utf-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.utf-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.utf-8
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.utf-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.utf-8
 [7] LC_PAPER=C                 LC_NAME=C
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.utf-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] wrswoR_0.0.6   logging_0.6-92 Rcpp_0.10.3    devtools_1.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] digest_0.6.3    evaluate_0.4.3  httr_0.2        memoise_0.1
[5] parallel_2.15.3 RCurl_1.95-4.1  stringr_0.6.2   tools_2.15.3
[9] whisker_0.1
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning your question

> But where do I place roxygen2 comments for this function?

I have to disappoint you that here simply is *no* support for roxygen(2) in Rcpp Attributes.  Maybe you want to contribute that?

On the other hand, writing normal C++ functions in `src/` and calling them from normal R functions is of course supported, and can be used by roxygen2 just fine.

As to what devtools does to your package: Also no idea. Neither Romain nor myself uses  devtools, so you are in undocumented and undefined territory.

Comment: Could you please take a look at https://github.com/muelleki/wrswoR (working version) and/or https://github.com/muelleki/wrswoR/tree/0.0.6 (broken version)? Perhaps I'm missing something very basic...

Comment: No, sorry, I can't do custom debugging for you.  But the project has a mailing list where others chime in too.  Maybe you could use that?

Comment: That's fine. Thanks to your answer, I can now reproduce the erroneous behavior in machine **A** after upgrading `devtools` to 1.1. A weird interaction...

Comment: So far, I can live with maintaining the documentation for exported Rcpp functions in a separate `.R` file. Perhaps this becomes a pain once there are very many such functions.

Comment: Sounds good. I think JJ stated that "eventually" this should be supported just from C++ files too, but such a parser extension needs to written first. Maybe you want to help? ;-)

Comment: I could take a look. What would be the best place to look at documentation for Rcpp attributes?

Comment: The corresponding vignette, and the code.  And questions on rcpp-devel :)